# Creating a GUI with ActionListeners inside a method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, windowlistener

I have a method inside one of my classes to my Java application that makes a Swing GUI and has it's own action listeners - which works fine. However, when the window is closed  I need the method to return a `String[]` array; this is the part that is causing the problems...

I have added a simple `return` statement at the end of the method, but obviously Java doesn't wait for the action listeners and thinks that the method is complete once the action listeners have been  added. So is there any way to *"hold"* a method, and then resume it when I am ready  - or even, a different solution to my problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Andy, can you post your code? It might give us a better idea what you are trying to do?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you wouldn't want to "hold" a method here, but rather hold a *state*.  Then as the others note in the good answers below, get this state in your WindowListener.

Comment: I will try to reiterate. What I really need to do is stop the method from returning (i.e finishing) until an action listener has been called which populates the array to be returned!

Comment: Please rewrite the second paragraph.  It makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: BTW - one good way to help explain a problem is to post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  It may not contain the information as to *why* the programmer chose the approach they did - but will answer many other questions (including the question "'What' does the code do now?").

Comment: try @Androw Thompson Solution

Comment: Andrew, Sorry about the SSCCE thing; - you have mentioned it on one of my previous questions but the truth is: I am working on a commercial program (so I've got to take intellectual property into account), and I don't really have time to write meaningless and shortened versions of my code, so I hoped that my written explanation would be vivid enough for someone to provide me with a working solution and luckily it was this time! @Neifen Yes, I have tried Andrew's solution and it is exactly what I needed thank you. (Please don't think I am accusing any member of infringing property righs, etc..)

Comment: @toto2: It is irrelevant now, but just to clear your mind: what I meant my second paragraph is: when you attach an action listener to a component the method just continues and the action listener is like another thread. For some reason I thought that by adding an action listener the method wouldn't reach the end until it was told to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane` instead.  The code that opened it will pause at that point - until the modal component is dismissed from the screen.

Comment: don't forget to set the JDialog Modal with `setModal(true);`

Comment: @Neifen  +1 but I prefer to specify the modality in the [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#constructor_summary) if possible.  If only because it is one less line of code.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Very sorry for the delayed reply, and thank you very much for your answer. A Modal JDialog is exactly what I needed...

Comment: You're welcome.  :-)  And as far as reply timing goes, (shrugs) 72 hours is more like a 'delayed reply' IMO - and I have asked questions that got answers that have stood longer than *that* before I replied with any further comment.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

try it with a [WindowListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) so when you close the window, you can send your array

as example:

```
public class YourClass{
    ...
    window.addWindowListener(new NameOfListener());
    ...

    class NameOfListener() extends WindowAdapter{
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(final WindowEvent e)
        {
            // send your array
            anInstanceYouWish.setArrayXY(yourStringArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply and thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, your solution does not work for me for a couple of reasons. 1) It is a method that creates the GUI and not a class, and 2) I do have a Window Listener but whenever I try to use it to return the array, my IDE just tells me to change the return type from `void`, therefore the return statement is not actually for the parent method.

Comment: 1) how do you create the Gui in your method? 2) A Listener can not have a return statement. So you have to make a set method there where you want your Array.

Comment: I create the GUI in the method just like you normally do: create a JPanel with some JComponents, add action listeners, and set the JPanel as the content pane in a JFrame! I don't think you understand my situation correctly though. Let's say I have a button named "Return" with an action listener attached. I only want to return the array, and finish the method when that button is pressed...

Comment: You'll also have to be careful with synchronization since the method that sets the array value is running in the GUI thread, but the method that will read the read is running in the main thread.

Comment: For tips on getting a link to the latest JavaDocs, see [point 2](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [`WindowListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) to the `JFrame` instance and override the [`windowClosing(WindowEvent e)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) method. And therein, you can implement your own behavior.

Comment: top-level container not only for the JFrame +1

Comment: @mKorbel +1, I made an assumption, but you're right - this applies to all top-level containers.

Comment: what is better WindowsClosing or WindowsClosed?

Comment: @mre: as I have said to Neifen, the problem with doing this is that the return statement is not for the parent method. Plus, the method will still continue after the action/window listener(s) have been added. I think what I really need is a way of pausing the actual method so that the action listener can resume it when the information is ready... Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: this WindowListener would be declared only once, for whole JVM instance, and returns top-level and its event(s), are you expecting more than that...

Comment: @mKorbel: I am not expecting anything. As I have said to Neifen, I just want to make it so my array only returns (i.e the method only finishes) when a button is pressed...

Comment: could you maybe post the code  of your method (or a part of it) so we can help you better?